# Is that mandatory for stored procedure parameter name should match with parameter passed from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure as below,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Test()
    @Name VARCHAR(10),
    @Dept VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

And I'm calling the stored procedure from C# like this:

```
SqlCommand scCommand = new SqlCommand("SP_Test", MysqlCon);
scCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

scCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "SomeVal";
scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "SomeVal";
...
...
```

Here I have given name that is different from procedure parameter name, so will that cause any errors?

Comment: Why not run the code and see for yourself? How do you expect the framework to map parameters and values if there is no relationship between them?

Comment: ADO.NET passes parameters to SQL Server by name, not by position. So yes, that will cause errors -- you can't pass parameters that aren't formally part of the definition, and you must pass parameters that have no default values.

Comment: @danish, no.of parameter and type is same, so I didn't get any error for this.

Comment: Incidentally, you should [avoid the `sp_` prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) when naming your own procedures. It's reserved for Microsoft's procedures.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I thought it stood for [Homer voice]Stupid Procedure[/Homer voice]. I worked wonders as far as application maintenance or debugging was concerned.

Comment: @danish - consider the T-SQL grammar. Identify any situation where a stored procedure name can appear where it's ambiguous with any other type of object. (Same for most other object types in SQL Server. The only ambiguity is between tables and views and *that* ambiguity is actually desirable)

Comment: okay, thanks for the comments and clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is Mandatory to have the same name as in the Stored Procedure Parameter because of the compiler map the Parameters based on the names so if you give a different name, it won't be able to map the values

So your C# Code should be something like this

```
scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "SomeVal";
scCommand.Parameters.Add("@Dept", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "SomeVal";
```

Comment: What if I have only two parameters in SP and Im passing only two parameters values from C#. So it won't match by order?

Comment: You don't have to match the order in this case, but instead you need to make sure that the Parameter names are spelled correctly

Comment: @MagendranV: If your question is "can I pass parameters by position somehow", you should probably ask *that* instead of asking if "it will cause any errors". But there's really no good reason not to know the names of your stored procedure parameters -- relying on parameter order is deeply problematic, especially when combined with T-SQL's baroque rules for implicit conversions.